# Troubleshooting - A single website is not accessible

Tags: dns, internet, website

There is a specific health related website that I am not able to access from my laptop running windows 10. The error I get in chrome is :

```
This site can’t be reached

The webpage at http://www.apneaboard.com/forums/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED
```

I have tried to access this site through 3 different browsers with no luck. Funny thing is, the website is accessible through other devices like phone and tab on the same network. Website is also accessible on the same laptop if I use a VPN and connect through a different country. The website isn't banned - it is accessible locally on a mate's computer and can browse in an internet cafe.

My ISP provides internet on an NBN connection as it does to a few million people in Australia and there no restrictions on my router.

What can I do to troubleshoot this ?

Edit : Based on the messages and answers, I am updating the following : 
1) ipconfig /flushdns has no effect on this issue. The site still remains unreachable
2) Following are the nslookup outcomes of the website. First without VPN second with VPN

```
C:\>nslookup apneaboard.com
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  2001:8003:a05b:1b00::1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out

C:\>nslookup apneaboard.com
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  2001:8003:a05b:1b00::1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
                                                                                              DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
```

3)Pinging the website on or off the vpn gives this message :

```
Ping request could not find host www.apneaboard.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

4) The DNS set for my wifi connection is already the google dns : 
IPv4 settings

Obtain an IP address automatically is selected. 
Preferrd DNS server is 8.8.8.8 and alternate is 8.8.4.4

This continues to baffle me. The website is still accessible through vpn and not through my regular connection. Any other troubleshooting steps please ?

Edit 2 : 
There is absolutely nothing in my hosts file. All lines are commented out
I tried using the IP address of the site (which I got from a ping through vpn - and I see the same page I see when I access http://IP while connected to vpn (which is a Sorry - If you are the owner of this website, please contact your hosting provider - page)
I have tried by disabling IPV6 and no luck. Still works through the vpn when ipv6 is disabled. I have also downloaded and used the microsoft solution to disable ipv6 just to be sure, aside from unchecking it from n/w properties. 
Following is the nslookup -d2 output :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\>nslookup -d2 www.apneaboard.com
------------
SendRequest(), len 38
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer (82 bytes):
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa
        type = PTR, class = IN, dlen = 32
        name = google-public-dns-a.google.com
        ttl = 86399 (23 hours 59 mins 59 secs)

------------
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

------------
SendRequest(), len 44
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        www.apneaboard.com.gateway, type = A, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer (119 bytes):
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        www.apneaboard.com.gateway, type = A, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  (root)
        type = SOA, class = IN, dlen = 64
        ttl = 86397 (23 hours 59 mins 57 secs)
        primary name server = a.root-servers.net
        responsible mail addr = nstld.verisign-grs.com
        serial  = 2017042400
        refresh = 1800 (30 mins)
        retry   = 900 (15 mins)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 86400 (1 day)

------------
------------
SendRequest(), len 44
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        www.apneaboard.com.gateway, type = AAAA, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer (119 bytes):
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        www.apneaboard.com.gateway, type = AAAA, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  (root)
        type = SOA, class = IN, dlen = 64
        ttl = 86396 (23 hours 59 mins 56 secs)
        primary name server = a.root-servers.net
        responsible mail addr = nstld.verisign-grs.com
        serial  = 2017042400
        refresh = 1800 (30 mins)
        retry   = 900 (15 mins)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 86400 (1 day)

------------
------------
SendRequest(), len 36
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 4, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        www.apneaboard.com, type = A, class = IN

------------
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
SendRequest failed
------------
SendRequest(), len 36
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 5, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        www.apneaboard.com, type = AAAA, class = IN

------------
                                                                                                            DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
SendRequest failed
*** Request to google-public-dns-a.google.com timed-out
```

Comment: Try to do a nslookup on the adress with and without VPN.

Comment: And after you have done what MikaelKjaer suggests, try loading onto your browser the IP address you obtained thru the VPN, but **outside** the VPN.

Comment: try to use Google's DNS rather than the ISP's DNS. follow howtogeek instructions, just only change the DNS and leave Obtain IP as Auto. (use the same DNS numbers (8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4)    https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/

Comment: What about your /etc/HOSTS file? Is it blocking this specific site?

Comment: Can you see what happens after your disable IPv6? It looks like your computer is using IPv6 resolution and failing. My guess is your other devices are using IPv4 to access the site (and that your VPN is only configured for IPv4).

Comment: Please post the output of the command `nslookup -d2 apneaboard.com`. You can probably replace the NSLOOKUP output you already have with the output of this command as it's the same information, just with more debugging detail.

Comment: Just a shot in the Dark but is it blocked in your Host file or anything of that nature. I know some VPNS can bypass the host file.

Comment: Try running "netsh int ip set dns" and "netsh winsock reset" without the quotes in cmd prompt.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin First command syntax is invalid. Ran the second command and restarted - no luck

Comment: It turns out there was an internet outage and my ISPs alternate provider kicked in. The site accessed alright. When my ISPs service was restored, almost magically, I was able to access this site.

Answer (score 2):

*Sometimes* ISPs mess up and things arn't routable.

Lets rule out the rediculously basic - `ipconfig /flushdns` should flush the dns cache for the PC.

nslookup for me brings up

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  2404:e800:103:3::68

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    apneaboard.com
Address:  104.193.110.187
Aliases:  www.apneaboard.com
```

There's two clear places where this could be broken - if your nslookup fails, its certainly DNS. If that works

I'd start my running a traceroute or pathping (Pathping is cool!) to both the IP and domain name.

At this point though, you know what's broken, but chances are its the ISP that has to fix it. I once had a website inaccessible for 2-3 months, then suddenly work.

Answer (score 2):

The error points at DNS. However, other devices on the network don't have the problem, meaning it's on the machine. I'd try running from command prompt:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ping apneaboard.com
nslookup apneaboard.com
```

If nslookup succeeds (similarly to @Journeyman's output) but ping fails or finds a different address, then some local name resolution is interfering. Could be:

- something in `%systemroot%\drivers\etc\hosts`
- Some local LSP doing weird stuff - run `netsh winsock show catalog`, compare the output to a working machine's, and maybe you'll find the culprit.